# Error: POST http://... 500 (Internal Server Error). Angular и X-XSRF-TOKEN (xsrf). Не проходят запросы методами POST, DELETE... Почему? Что делать?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, angularjs, laravel

Я явно что-то упускаю, но что?

1. Есть два локальных сайта на Laravel5.1 + Angular1.4.7.
2. Второй является точной копией первого. Обращаются к одной БД, и отличаются только ключом APP_KEY в настройках Laravel-a.
3. Первый без проблем шлет запросы POST и DELETE и получает корректные ответы.
4. Второй же выдает ошибки типа: *POST http://... 500 (Internal Server Error).* При том, что GET запросы проходят без проблем на обоих сайтах.

Почему такое происходит? Что я упускаю?

Это важно потому, что собираюсь его копировать в продакшн, но если там будет такая же проблема, то боль.

Comment: `Второй же выдает ошибки типа: POST http://... 500 (Internal Server Error).` какие ошибки выдает? Laravel должен сказать что конкретно не так

Comment: Я так понимаю, что до Laravel-а дело не доходит. Это Angular препятствует отправке данных. В консоли вижу: `POST http://laravel.loc/api/order 500 (Internal Server Error). angular.js:10722 DELETE http://laravel.loc/api/customers/9 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Я рекомендую все же проверить содержимое `storage\logs\laravel.log` и приложить его к вопросу, если там есть ошибки, записанные во время запроса.

Comment: Спасибо за указание, куда еще можно заглядывать в случае чего, но по теме моих вопросов информация там отсутствует. Последние ошибки никак не связаны с текущей проблемой. В файл laravel.log, при возникновении описанной ситуации, ничего не добавляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 HTTP статус говорит о ошибке на стороне сервере. Эта ошибка либо при обработке запроса сервером (`nginx` или `apache`) либо ошибка в коде. Соответственно смотри логи сервера, php и приложения. Место нахождение логов надо смотреть в конфигах. Если у вас Unix система то логи лежат *скорее всего* тут:

```
/var/log/apache2/...
/var/log/nginx/...
path_to_project/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: Ну вот знал же об этом обо всем ))) Но в очередной раз на те же грабли. Были не установлены права доступа к папкам.